# cPanel with PHP selector shows WordPress Error "PHP installation appears to be missing the MySQL extension which is required by WordPress"

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, cpanel, mariadb

After an upgrade of MySQL to use MariaDB 10, multiple sites on my CloudLinux cPanel server are just white screens with `Error: Your PHP installation appears to be missing the MySQL extension which is required by WordPress`

I can choose the PHP version per account, but selecting any from 5.3 up to 5.6 still doesn't work.

Nothing is working, rebuilding Apache and PHP using `/scripts/easyapache/` is not working, and running `<?php echo phpinfo(); ?>` on the failing sites shows there is no `mysql` or `mysqli` extension.

How can this be fixed?

Comment: Do you have root access? If so, try `sudo service apache restart` to start with (assuming Ubuntu). If that does not help, have you looked at your php.ini file?

Comment: I did restart Apache first, and in fact even rebuilt it later - to no avail. The problem turned out to be the result of a MySQL upgrade - the symlinks to mysql.so, mysqli.so and pso_mysql.so were all broken - I answered the question below.

Comment: Ooh, righto. Did you do the MySQL upgrade manually? If so, was it a major version change (5.5 to 5.6, for example)? It is worth letting this update with the operating system to be safe - and if you have to do a manual upgrade, set up a new/separate MySQL database server, copy the database there, and repoint the app to the new server. That way you'll not have a panic if an upgrade does not go to plan.

Comment: I didn't do the upgrade manually. Either my hosting guys did it (I have a dedicated box) or it was an automatic upgrade. Hence the complete shock and not knowing what caused it. Great advice though for any future upgrades - cheers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may NOT require big rebuilds or reinstallation of PHP/MySQL if you are running MySQL/MariaDB on your cPanel server - which is quite likely if you are running 64-bit CloudLinux.

It might just be broken symlinks to the modules.

If you log into WHM and search for "MariaDB" you may find an option "MySQL/MariaDB Upgrade" - this means you are using it. Alternatively you can just ask your host if MySQL/MariaDB is the database management system.

If you **are** using MariaDB, an upgrade may have broken symlinks to `mysql.so`, `mysqli.so` and `pdo_mysql.so`.

Only attempt the following if you have root access via the command line and know what you are doing - otherwise ask your host to do it.

Create a file called `info.php` in the web root of your broken site, with the following code:

```
<?php 
    $inipath = php_ini_loaded_file();

    if ($inipath)
    {
        echo 'Loaded php.ini: ' . $inipath;
    } else 
    {
        echo "No php.ini - MariaDB symlinks are NOT the problem";
    }
?>
```

This will give you the path to the php.ini file of PHP build you are using when you navigate to `http://www.yoursite.com/info.php`.

In my case it showed `/opt/alt/php55/etc/php.ini`

This is PHP 5.5 which has been selected via the PHP selector in cPanel. The first part of this: `/opt/alt/php55/` shows where we need to look in the next step.

Now, log in via the command line and run:

```
cd /opt/alt/php55/usr/lib64/php/modules 
ls -la
```

Look down the list and see if you can find something like:

```
mysql.so -> /opt/alt/php55/etc/mysql10/mysql.so
```

If what appears between `/etc/****/mysql.so` is not `mariadb10` (or whatever version of MariaDB you are running) then you need to rebuild the symlinks.

```
unlink mysql.so
unlink mysqli.so
unlink pdo_mysql.so

ln -s /opt/alt/php55/etc/mariadb10/mysql.so /opt/alt/php55/usr/lib64/php/modules/mysql.so
ln -s /opt/alt/php53/etc/mariadb10/mysqli.so /opt/alt/php55/usr/lib64/php/modules/mysqli.so
ln -s /opt/alt/php53/etc/mariadb10/pdo_mysql.so /opt/alt/php55/usr/lib64/php/modules/pdo_mysql.so
```

Then you may need to do the same for other PHP versions available via the PHP selector. In my case this involved also repairing:

```
/opt/alt/php53/usr/lib64/php/modules 
/opt/alt/php54/usr/lib64/php/modules 
/opt/alt/php56/usr/lib64/php/modules
```

It was a complete horror story, but very easily fixed in the end (after rebuilds and other dead-end avenues).

Comment: I am only a cPanel re-seller, so I have no privileges to access `/opt/....`. How can I solve this issue so please ?

Answer (score 1):

The cpanel forum discussion has  helped me to resolve the case.  In my case we have recently moved from easyapache3 to easyapache4 and custom "suPHP_config" directive of ea3 was found causing the issue.  Once it is disabled it worked good again.

https://forums.cpanel.net/threads/mysql-extension-missing.554251/

Answer (score 0):

Same problem here, and I found this solution:

```
extension=mysql.so
extension=mysqli.so
extension=pdo_mysql.so
```

these lines should be added to all of php.ini files:

```
/opt/alt/php44/etc/php.ini
/opt/alt/php51/etc/php.ini
/opt/alt/php52/etc/php.ini
/opt/alt/php53/etc/php.ini
/opt/alt/php54/etc/php.ini
/opt/alt/php55/etc/php.ini
/opt/alt/php55/etc/php.ini
/opt/alt/php70/etc/php.ini
```

Answer (score -1):

I have the same problem, but it seems *not* to be a symlink related issue:

```
root@cpanel [/opt/alt/php55/usr/lib64/php/modules]# mysql -V
mysql  Ver 15.1 Distrib 10.0.24-MariaDB, for Linux (x86_64) using readline 5.1

root@cpanel [/opt/alt/php55/usr/lib64/php/modules]# pwd
/opt/alt/php55/usr/lib64/php/modules`

root@cpanel [/opt/alt/php55/usr/lib64/php/modules]# ls -la *mysql*
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root         38 Apr 12 10:02 mysqli.so -> /opt/alt/php55/etc/mariadb10/mysqli.so
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root linksafe 264176 Mar  3 10:09 mysqlnd.so*
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root         37 Apr 12 10:02 mysql.so -> /opt/alt/php55/etc/mariadb10/mysql.so
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root linksafe 132512 Mar  3 10:09 nd_mysqli.so*
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root linksafe  49448 Mar  3 10:09 nd_mysql.so*
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root linksafe  28704 Mar  3 10:09 nd_pdo_mysql.so*
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root         41 Apr 12 10:02 pdo_mysql.so -> /opt/alt/php55/etc/mariadb10/pdo_mysql.so`
```

Are there any other showstoppers what can cause this problem?

Answer (score -2):

You might want to check the first entry of the site. Most of the time, if it's a Wordpress site, I debug the site first in app level.

So I first look at .htaccess and reset everything there. So I leave just one piece of code-block from wordpress:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

.. if it solves the problem then there should be an issue with plugins sticking directives that should not be there.

Sometimes I got the same error message when Wordfence WAF is not compatible with newer php versions after a cPanel upgrade.

Comment: Answer not for problme. It's simple copy & paste and without any value to the question or in any case to mislead the user